# How to export ssas cube values to a file

Tags: excel, csv, sharepoint-2013, ssas

I'm looking to export ssas cube values to a csv file. I would like to query the cube, using excel pivot tables or excel cubemembers/cubevalues, and then have some scheduled task to refresh the data from the cube and then export the numbers to a flat file, such as csv.

The flat file is to be read into a SharePoint list once a day.

Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Vinnie.

We have tried using PowerPivot with Scheduled refresh in SharePoint. This does not work, probably due to some lack of configuration in SharePoint.

We have also tried using a mdx query together with a SSIS package, but this will require a lot of knowledge to maintain if we want to alter the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using openquery for this. Materializing the openquery into a sql server db table.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Reporting Services running in SharePoint integrated mode? If so then use Report Builder drag-n-drop MDX query editor to create the query and schedule a subscription to export to CSV in a SharePoint list.

Comment: Hi, Greg. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately we don't use Reporting Services in our business.